# How to redirect to Location from a response header from API - Angular 12?

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular version 12. I want to call the API that returns Location header and make the Angular to redirect to that header but I do not know how to deal with it. Below is the code I normally call regular API.

My component:

```
this.myService.submitForm(formData).subscribe( data => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

My service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

submitForm(formData) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/submitPayment`, formData);
}
```

When I use above approach, I will get this error on a Chrome browser,

> Failed to load response data: No content available because this request was redirected

together with 302 http status code.

Below is the response header from the API

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Please share the full api url. Also what type is this.http ? did you import httpClientModule ?

Comment: I added the response header from API and showed that I did import HttpClient module. @KLTR

Comment: Are you redirecting to the location in the response ? 
https://kinsta.com/blog/http-302/

Answer (score 0):

@Hikaru. I would suggest to use in this case "Response Interceptor" - [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). In the interceptor you can access to any header of response and do anything what you need. But be aware that interceptor will intercept all requests from your application, so you'll need to check somehow that exact response with redirection.
Also, in the response interceptor you can implement global error handling in you your app. Just check responses for errors and do what you need on errors from the backend. Everything in the one place.